# Why cant a QToolButton be hidden after it is added to a QToolBar?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtoolbar

This works...

```
QToolButton * toolbutton = new QToolButton(this);

//hide before addWidget
toolbutton->hide();

addWidget(toolbutton);
```

But this doesn't

```
QToolButton * toolbutton = new QToolButton(this)

addWidget(toolbutton);

//hide after addWidget
toolbutton->hide();
```

Is there an alternative so I can actually hide after a QToolButton after it is added to a QToolBar? I need to during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to add a QAction instead of a widget and then hide the QAction. I've tried it and it works with QAction::setVisible(false).

You can also do something like QToolBar::actions().at(3)->setVisible(false); if you know the position of the widget in the QToolBar.

Answer (score 7):

`QAction * QToolBar::addWidget ( QWidget * widget )`

You should hide returned QAction

Comment: Interesting suggestion. This would be an elegant solution if the majority of your toolbar items are QActions and only have one or two QWidgets on it.

Comment: Even if you add QWidget to QToolBar it will return `QAction *` for it: `QAction * QToolBar::addWidget ( QWidget * widget )`

Answer (score 0):

```
toolbar->actions().at(0)->setVisible(false);
```